# navitaging through ref in oracle

Tags: oracle, ref

I'm working with Oracle 11gR2, and i'm having doubts with objects which contains REFS. Watching the  next picture:

[image]

And knowing that the that the table emp_ps is a table of emp_typ, i can't understand how the sentence in the picture is correct. Shouldn't be the ref fields unreachable through the "." operator? I thought that i had to deref the value of  "e.dept" into an aux varibale of emp_typ, and then and only then I would be able to navigate through the fields of aux!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need [`DEREF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions054.htm#SQLRF00634) to return the object as a whole.
Documentation allows implicit [dot-dereferencing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions011.htm#SQLRF52088), multi-level nested too.
[image]